# Язык программирования Python

Tags: python

Какие сильные стороны языка Python и слабые? В чём он лучше всех, если брать например реальную задачу?

Comment: чтоб сравнивать на реальных задачах - нужен хотяб список реальных задач)

Answer (score 3):

**Сильные:**

1. Многозадачность, многообразие
2. Большое комьюнити
3. Куча библиотек, практически для всего что можно придумать
4. Простота использования и обучения
5. Много ресурсов для обучения

**Слабые:**

1. Средняя скорость
2. Не совсем удобный синтаксис некоторых модулей

Comment: Реализация библиотек на си, перенесенная для использования питоновцами, бывает довольно неприветливой, а ошибки в таких библиотеках могут быть очень неинформативными. К примеру cv2. Ооо да. Все ошибки самому искать, хорошо хоть строчку подсказывает. Но все же по мне так это не такой уж и недостаток самого python'а как языка.

Comment: скорость это спорный момент. есть проект ейлера в котором есть решения на 5 строк и на 50 строк.на 1 сек и на часы. для любого языка. говнокод можно на любом языке написать. также верно что и проэкты на питоне работают с приемлемой скоростью.

Comment: «средняя скорость» и не поспоришь. Очевидным это становится при обработке изображений - матриц, скажем, 1280 пикселей на 720 пикселей, и в каждом пикселе, скажем, по 3 канала (RGB). Ужасный сон python'а. Поэтому такие моменты реализованы на си в модулях вроде numpy. Очень весомая разница в скорости. Поэтому можно сказать, что python скорей стоит использовать обдумано, переключаясь в таких задачах на более лучшее решение в специализированых модулях.